# Task exception on worker thread: java.lang.IllegalAccessError

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, firebase-cloud-messaging

What does this error mean:

```
 Task exception on worker thread: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Method 'void android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.<init>()' is inaccessible to class 'com.google.firebase.iid.zzg' (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.iid.zzg' appears in /data/app/name.name.name.name-1/base.apk): com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzt.zzEd(Unknown Source)
```

I am new to android, so I have no idea what can be wrong. 
I tried to change versions of android support, but it gives another errors in another places. I googled solutions here [java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Method 'void android.support.v4.content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40904466/java-lang-illegalaccesserror-method-void-android-support-v4-content) and here [java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Method 'void android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.' is inaccessible to class 'com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41955051/java-lang-illegalaccesserror-method-void-android-support-v4-content-contextcom). But it did not help me. I am trying to make it work for two weeks and do not know what to do.

I am getting it when doing this:

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("name");
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
```

My build.gradle (app):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "name.name.name.name"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 2
        versionName "2.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.8.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0'
    compile files('libs/urlimageviewhelper-1.0.4.jar')
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'
    compile 'com.github.ksoichiro:android-observablescrollview:1.6.0'
    compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.2.1'
    compile 'com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1'
    debugCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.5'
    releaseCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5'
    testCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5'
    compile 'it.sephiroth.android.library.horizontallistview:hlistview:1.2.2'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
 }

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

build.gradle (project):

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: put your top gradle file here to better help

Comment: @BrunoFerreira I did so

Comment: try to change 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.0' to 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.2'

Comment: @BrunoFerreira still the same error

Comment: Did you solve it?