# Java Error on Android Studio java.lang.IllegalAccessError

Tags: java, android

I've already read questions about this problem ([This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48487002/java-lang-illegalaccesserror-method-void-android-support-v4-content-contextcom) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41955051/java-lang-illegalaccesserror-method-void-android-support-v4-content-contextcom)) and I've tried to apply the solutions to my case but it didn't work for me

The line who causes an error is this

```
InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(LoginActivity.this);
```

Whit this error on Log

> java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Method 'void
>   android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.' is inaccessible to class
>   'com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd'

Here is my build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'

    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
        javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "there is an id here"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        multiDexEnabled true
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            //proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url "https://s3.amazonaws.com/repo.commonsware.com"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support:multidex-instrumentation:1.0.1') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'multidex'
    }
    compile 'com.commonsware.cwac:cam2:0.4.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
    compile project(':viewPagerIndicator')
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.26.0' //CAMBIO DA 4.7.0 a 4.26.0
    //compile project(':facebook')
    /*compile files('libs/android-maven-plugin-3.6.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/apache-mime4j-benchmark-0.7.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/apache-mime4j-core-0.7.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/apache-mime4j-dom-0.7.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/apache-mime4j-examples-0.7.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/apache-mime4j-storage-0.7.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/braintree-api-1.2.7.jar')
    compile files('libs/commons-codec-1.6.jar')
    compile files('libs/fluent-hc-4.2.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpclient-4.2.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpclient-cache-4.2.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpcore-4.2.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpmime-4.2.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/libGoogleAnalytics.jar')
    compile files('libs/metadata-extractor-2.6.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/xmpcore.jar')*/
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.3.0'

}
```

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40904466/java-lang-illegalaccesserror-method-void-android-support-v4-content.

Comment: As those play services are very out of date, when did this start to occur? What was the change that triggered it?

Comment: Upgrade your `buildToolsVersion` to a more recent one (or comment the line as it's now automatically managed by Android Studio (if you're using Android plugin for Gradle 3.0.0 or higher)

Comment: After update my Facebook SDK version @weston

Answer (score 0):

Exclude Support Library from `facebook SDK`

```
compile ('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.26.0'){
exclude module: 'support-v4'
exclude group: 'com.android.support'
}
```